# Multithread in android runnable service

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I create and i start a new thread. Could someone confirm that global variable of the class normally declared (i.e. private int x = 5) are readable in the other thread?

I am creating a service and before return in onStartCommand i start my new thread by        new Thread(new Analyzing()).start() where Analyzing is the some class of the service that implements Runnable.

By debug i saw that when the new thread is started and is running the code in run(), the global variable are reset.

ABC of multithread says that threads share code and data, i dont understand this behavior.

The code here: http://pastebin.com/wiuwm1gf

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone confirm that global variable of the class normally declared (i.e. private int x = 5) are readable in the other thread?

Public global variable (instance or `static`) at class level is readable by other thread, but there is no guarantees about what value you'll get after reading. To ensure visibility guarantees, usually you need to make this variable `volatile`. Consider reading [this article](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.ru/2007/08/atomicity-visibility-and-ordering.html) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone confirm that global variable of the class normally declared (i.e. >private int x = 5) are readable in the other thread?

It is visible, but when a modified ordinary value is available to other threads is not guaranteed. You should make it volatile.  Java volatile keyword is used to mark a Java variable as "being stored in main memory". That means that every read of a volatile variable will be read from the computer's main memory, and not from the CPU cache, and that every write to a volatile variable will be written to main memory, and not just to the CPU cache.
I suggest you this article/links:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html

[java: are global variables visible in threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865256/java-are-global-variables-visible-in-threads)

Bye bye